# How to update a row in a simple approach

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate

I'm confused. I want to update a row but to find the simple instruction of how to do it is very complicated.

Do you have any suggestion how to update a row in Nhibernate?

If my table named candy has 4 column (one of them is a primary key) and I want to update one column only.

How should I write in the hbm.xml and the c# code?

```
Candy
--------------
number (PK)     Size     Color    Sex
```

Answer (score 0):

i've never used nhibernate but in normal sql it is pretty straight forward.
UPDATE yourtable SET columnToUpdate=newValue WHERE yourPK=yourPKValue

for how to execute sql queries against a database check the online help on SqlConnection and SqlCommand